# Vertically center and wrap text around another div

Tags: html, css, web

I'm at a loss here, I've been trying various things for a couple hours trying to get some text to center itself vertically in another div when it is only one line. When there are multiple times, it looks great and wraps beautifully.

Here is a photo of what I'm talking about:
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpp2b.png)

How can I fix the first instance (one line only) so it is centered vertically in the box? [Here's a bootply.](https://www.bootply.com/xE9sYjFGOb)

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The code should be posted here, rather than on external sites, so that users can help you without leaving Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text you want to center in an HTML element and center that element using flexbox:

```css
.list-item {
  min-height: 52px;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin:  5px 0;
}

.list-item-status-container {
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-left: 6px solid #90CAF9;
  background-color: #E3F2FD;
  max-width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.list-item-status-content {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.list-item-content {
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list-item-content p,
.list-item-status-content > div {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.list-item-content > div {
  width: 200px;
}

.item-unchecked-box {
  color: #BDBDBD;
  padding-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="list-item">
  <div class="list-item-status-container">
    <div class="list-item-status-content">
      <div>
        <div class="item-unchecked-box">
          <i class="fas fa-square fa-lg"></i>
        </div>
        Warning <i style="padding-left: 4px;" class="fas fa-caret-down status-caret-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item-content">
    <p>This should be vertically centered if there is room.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <div class="list-item-status-container">
    <div class="list-item-status-content">
      <div>
        <div class="item-unchecked-box">
          <i class="fas fa-square fa-lg"></i>
        </div>
        Warning <i style="padding-left: 4px;" class="fas fa-caret-down status-caret-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, esse deleniti odio fugiat culpa excepturi enim omnis laborum distinctio officia odit laudantium aliquid sint, ad expedita alias. Voluptatem, eveniet, odio.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need css to set the parent container to `display: table;` then the container as `display:table-cell;`

```
.list-item-content{
height: 350px;  width: 250px; background-color:#F1F1F1;
 display: table;
}
.list-item-content .cell{
  display:table-cell; text-align: center;  vertical-align: middle;
}

<div class="list-item-content">
  <div class='cell'>
    This should be vertically centered if there is room
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which "other div" is this wrapping around (as per OP)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `text-center` like below

```
          <div class="list-item-content text-center">
            This should be vertically centered if there is room
          </div>
        </div>
```

I'm assuming that you are using bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

```
.list-item-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 52px;
}

<div class="list-item-content">
    This should be vertically centered if there is room
</div>
```

Since you set the `min-height` of `.list-item` to be `52px`, that means it's also safe to assume `.list-item-context` `min-height` is also `52px`.

Comment: which "other div" is this wrapping around (as per OP)?